# Too many retag requests at once?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Going over the review queue for pending edits here on Stack Overflow, I saw that a certain user went over a lot of questions and fixed a commonly occurring tag [size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/size) with the more specific tag [image-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-size), in questions where it pertained to the size of images.

Now, the edit itself seems fine to me, and I don't think retagging should fall under "too minor" an edit (as opposed to editing content), but I don't know it if's advisable to approve too many of these minor retaggings at once.

In lower-traffic SE sites, this would bump all these questions to the top of the page, but on SO this probably won't be as noticeable.

What's the best thing to do in this situation? Approve them all, or let some of them sit in the queue and wait a bit before approving them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are obvious deficiencies left, doing minor retagging only in an edit is certainly "too minor". Still, you gave a good argument for superficial edits not doing noticeable harm:

> In lower-traffic SE sites, this would bump all these questions to the top of the page, *but on SO this probably won't be as noticeable*.

If the retagging was all that had to be done, approve it.

Letting it just sit in the queue simply does not work, there are too many robo-reviewers who will gladly approve anything.

Answer (score 4):

Leaving aside the question of whether a retag is actually "too minor" or not, I think you've answered your own question:

> In lower-traffic SE sites, this would bump all these questions to the top of the page, but on SO this probably won't be as noticeable.

Given the volume of new questions and answers on Stack Overflow a bunch of retags going through all at the same time won't have the same detrimental effect as it would on another site. Plus, the home page is automatically filtered for each user using their "favourite" tags and what tags they actually answer in.

So the only people who might notice are those that follow the [image-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-size) tag.